# Extract rows/columns from ** matrices in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, matrix

I have a square matrix `double **A`

I know how to iterate through this matrix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j ++) {
   int val = A[i][j];
   printf("val: %d\n", val);
 }
}
```

However, I'm wondering how I can assign an entire row or column to a variable given I have this `**` matrix (The `**` pointer to pointer nonsense is still a little confusing. I believe its saying a list of list of doubles).

To add a little more background, I'm trying to extract rows and columns so I can perform a `cuda` matrix multiplication. I see a lot of documentation online that uses one-dimensional vectors to represent matrices (i.e. `double* A`) However, I am getting confused with the `**`

Comment: `j <  i;` or `j < MATRIX_SIZE`? In C++ better use `std::array< std::array<int, MATRIX_SIZE>, MATRIX_SIZE>`

Comment: @MohitJain Oops, that's a typo. Fixing now. Thanks

Comment: You cannot assign an entire row or column to a variable.

Comment: do you want to convert the 2d array to 1d?

Comment: @Himanshu I'm not too familiar with memory management terminology. I guess maybe what I mean is a pointer to the first element in a row/column which, I think given contiguous memory, kind of represents the entire row/column. Am I right?

Comment: @skrtbhtngr I would also be interested in that as well. That would probably make things easier.

Comment: allocate space to a 1-d array and then you can use oneD_Array[i*MATRIX_SIZE+j]=A[i][j]

Comment: When you use a double pointer, you already have a pointer to the first element in each row. Access the first element using the pointer (a+i*MATRIX_SIZE). Correct me if a I am wrong please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two-dimensional array of doubles (`double **`) can be looked at as a one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays of doubles.

```
double **arr; // properly initialized
for(int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < MATRIX_SIZE; ++rowNumber)
{
    double *row = arr[rowNumber];
    // do something with this row
    for(int colNumber = 0; colNumber < MATRIX_SIZE; ++colNumber)
    {
        double value = row[colNumber];
        // do something with value
    }
}
```

In the above example, `row` is a pointer to a contiguous row of values from the initial array. This works because a two dimensional array is usually allocated like this:

```
double **arr = new double*[ROW_COUNT];
for(int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < ROW_COUNT; ++rowNumber)
{
    arr[rowNumber] = new double[COL_COUNT];
}
```

Getting a pointer to a column in the matrix (like we did with `row` above) is not possible because the values in a column are not contiguous, only the values in each row are contiguous.

Comment: @lonut Thanks for the explanation. I suppose if I wanted to get it for columns, I would first have to transpose the matrix.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Basically the program sees the memory as a one-dimensional array of locations and in this model you can only have a set of adjacent values/locations on a single dimension (so either rows or columns in your case, but not both at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
std::array< std::array<int, MATRIX_SIZE>, MATRIX_SIZE> A;

std::array<int, MATRIX_SIZE> ith_row = A[i];
std::array<int, MATRIX_SIZE> &ith_row_ref = A[i];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am constrained to a template which uses double** A :(

Answer (score 1):

You can assign rows to variables easily but you can't assign columns because of the way that memory is laid out.

You can think of double pointers like this.
The first pointer points to the item to give you the row.
 I'm going to make a 3w 4c matrix to show you an example

Theoretical (How you should think about it in your head)

```
Your first double pointer

  p
  |
  V      0 1 2  <-indexes
0 [p1]->[1,2,3] 
1 [p2]->[0,2,3]
2 [p3]->[1,0,3]
3 [p4]->[1,2,0]
```

which corresponds to the matrix

```
1,2,3
0,2,1
1,0,3
1,2,0
```

So you can thinking about getting the **0** at index **(1,0)** as

```
int **p = //some place that holds the matrix;
int *row2 = p[1];
int value = p[0];
```

The reason why it's not as straightforward as declaring a two dimensional
array is because when get the double pointer, you're not sure of the layout of the memory. The numbers could be stored like this

```
 p1 p3 p2 p4
 |  |  |  |
[123103021120...] <- //this is basically RAM or "memory"
```

and you would have no idea as the programmer.

I hope this cleared some things up!

Answer (score 1):

A[i][j] is a type of int, but A[i] is a int pointer, so if you want get a row to a variable, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i ++) {
    int* val = A[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j ++) {
        printf("%d\n", val[j]);
    }
}
```

but you can't get a column to a variable.